# PhpStorm not push committed changes

Tags: git, phpstorm, push

Every changes in **PhpStorm** were commit but not pushed! Without any error and message.

In fact, when I select *Commit and push*, this just commit changes and not push it.

Also, `git push` working in console.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please clarify whether Push dialog appears when you perform **Commit & Push?**

If not, it can be related to this issue:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-231545

Comment: Tnx, Yes! It was related to my system locale format!! worked on english (us)